# Signal server about user-client error from Boost Asio's async_read_some callback function

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, boost-asio

I'm trying to asynchronously read data from the HTTP server using `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`'s member function `async_read_some`

```
template<
    typename MutableBufferSequence,
    typename ReadHandler>
void-or-deduced async_read_some(
    const MutableBufferSequence & buffers,
    ReadHandler handler);
```

and I want to know a way how to signal the server that error happened on client's side of an application so that server stops trying to send the rest of the data to the client.

For example suppose I need 10 recursive `async_read_some` function calls to receive the whole answer from the server. When 4th `async_read_some` has called its `handler` function I fail to parse the received data within this `handler` function because exception of some kind is thrown. Now I want to inform the server that error happened and I don't want to receive the rest of the message. But how should I do this when I'm inside this `handler` function?

I could call`ip::tcp::socket::shutdown` with `ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_type::shutdown_receive` argument but than I can't use the same connection for future communication.

I also cant call `ip::tcp::socket`'s `cancel` member function that cancels ongoing asynchronous operations because at that point no asynchronous operations is actually being handled on that socket - only the callback function of asynchronous operation is being processed.

How should I handle this situation correctly if I don't want to close this connection?

Comment: Maybe I just should close the socket when some error happens and then create a new one behind the scenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should close connection. In general, you cannot use this connection for future communication. Especially if you do `shutdown` on it.

If you try to stay with this connection it can receive trash (because of reading part of a previous answer), send trash (because non-complete previous write) or just stay with broken connection (peer host think connection is closed).

I think any error for `async_read_some` (except operation_aborted) if fatal to this connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man! Already started to implement this but its good to know that someone else also thinks that this is the way to go :)